# Htaccess - Change domain based on language param

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I need help with a htaccess rewrite. Been asking Google for a while now...

I want this url:

```
http://www.examplenorwegian.no/sv/(wildcard)
```

To rewrite to:

```
http://www.exampleswedish.se/sv/(wildcard)
```

It is the **/sv/** part that is the key in this. So if the case is other way around, it will rewrite to norwegian url.

Could not get this to work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.examplenorwegian\.no/sv/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.exampleswedish.se/sv/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `%{HTTP_HOST}` variable *only* contains the hostname, no path information. The Path information must be matched in the rule's regex pattern or against the `%{REQUEST_URI}` variable:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.examplenorwegian\.no$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^sv/(.*)$ http://www.exampleswedish.se/sv/$1 [R=301,L]
```